# Position UIButton's inside image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have added a square image inside a UIButton. The goal is to have the square image on the left of the button, with space margin around 4 sides of button = 5.

Here is the code:

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left;
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
```

In interface builde, I tried in "Control" to align left, or play with insets to no avail.

and here is the result:

[image]

You can notice several problems:

1. Right margin is > 5 (between button and text)
2. Left margin > 5
3. The rest, aspect, and top and bottom margins are fine.

How to have this button well on the left, and the text right next to it?

Comment: So you want to add margin to all side of content and add space between text and image?. Also, content alignment is center or left?

Comment: I want to add margin on all sides of the image inside the button. Also I need the content left aligned: so I end up with image on the left + 5 margin, then image, then text with a distance of 5 from the image.

Comment: It looks like the national flag of Argentine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try custom `UIButton`

set image's frame in btn `func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect`

set title's frame in btn `func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect`

```
class CustomBtn: UIButton {

    
    
    let imgWidth: CGFloat = 16    // you set
    
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    
    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        
        // contentRect.minX + Left margin + imgWidth + Right margin
        let x = contentRect.minX + 5 + imgWidth + 5
        // contentRect.width - (Left margin + + imgWidth + Right margin) - btnTrailing
        let width = contentRect.width - (5 + imgWidth + 5) - 5
        let y = contentRect.minY + 5
        //  contentRect.height - inset.top - inset.bottom
        let h = contentRect.height - 5 - 5 
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: h)
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let x: CGFloat = 5
        // make image center Y
        let y = contentRect.minY + (contentRect.height - imgWidth) / 2
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imgWidth, height: imgWidth)
    }

}
```

---

For setting `imgWidth` dynamically,

```
class CustomBtn: UIButton {

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect { 
        //  grab full button's height, contentRect.height
        let imgWidth = imageWidth(for: contentRect.height)

        // as above 
        // contentRect.minX + Left margin + imgWidth + Right margin
        let x = contentRect.minX + 5 + imgWidth + 5
        // contentRect.width - (Left margin + + imgWidth + Right margin) - btnTrailing
        let width = contentRect.width - (5 + imgWidth + 5) - 5
        let y = contentRect.minY + 5
        //  contentRect.height - inset.top - inset.bottom
        let h = contentRect.height - 5 - 5 
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: h)
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        //  grab full button's height, contentRect.height
        let imgWidth = imageWidth(for: contentRect.height)
        
        // as above 
        let x: CGFloat = 5
        // make image center Y
        let y = contentRect.minY + (contentRect.height - imgWidth) / 2
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imgWidth, height: imgWidth)
    }

    func imageWidth(for btnHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
         return (btnHeight - CGFloat(5 * 2)) / 2
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, isn't fatalError() causing a problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working. For setting imgWidth dynamically, how would you grab full button's height up there?

Comment: Thanks. The previous version before you refactored the imageWidth function out worked. This one has error with the missing return function type. I can correct it of course, but for the sake of correctness, you should add it.

Comment: return type added

Answer (score 0):

First, adjust your button image resource's sizes to correct x2 or x3 in scale. Then try this class.

```
class DefaultButton: UIButton {
    @discardableResult
    func setImage(_ image: UIImage?) -> Self {
        if let image = image {
            self.imageView?.contentMode = .center
            self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
            self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
            self.titleEdgeInsets.left = (frame.width - (imageEdgeInsets.left + imageView!.frame.width) - titleLabel!.frame.width) / 2
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

```
let button = DefaultButton(type: .system)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 110, height: 60)
button.setTitle("FRANCE", for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "france"))
```

Here is my repo to achive these kind of UI, you can refer
https://github.com/haphanquang/FigmaKit

Comment: Thanks. I'm close to it with your subclass. Only thing is that scale aspectfit is not respected the image is distorted. How would you force respect aspect?

Comment: maybe set `btn.imageView.mode`